# how to get a div span class element

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

i am trying to display the number 1 in my console, apparently it did not work, any advise please

This is my code apparently it didn't work.

```
String error1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='label label-error']/span[@class='sidebar-label']")).getText();
```

[image: label tag]

the console error output

```
  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='label label-error']/span[@class='sidebar-label']"}
```

Comment: Did you invert the attributes from div and span elements ? `String error1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='sidebar-label']/span[@class='label label-error']")).getText();`

Comment: sorry,you mean this driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='sidebar-label']/div[@class='label label-error']")).getText(); ? same error

Comment: try this, i think your xpath is wrong `//div[@class="sidebar-label"]/span`

Comment: You are using wrong attribute values of class for div and span. Use the xpath suggested by @E.Wiest

Answer (score 1):

Your Xpath is Wrong, Use one of these:

1. `//div[@class="sidebar-label"]/span`
2. `//div[@class="sidebar-label"]/span[@class="label label-error"]`
3. `//*[@class="label label-error"]`